# How to make a very large heightmap with high resolution

Tags: height-map

I am trying to make a heightmap with a very large image with high resolution. it is around 15000 pixels by 15000 pixels.
I'll use the heightmap to export it into .dem or .obj files so that I can use it in gazebo simulator.
I have tried to subdivide a plane into 15000 vertices by 15000 vertices but my computer will stop at around 2500 vertices.
Currently, I am dividing the original heightmap into 36 pieces so that It could all add up to one large plane when brought into gazebo.
Is dividing the heightmap file and making parts the only way to make this heightmap? or is there another way to make Very large heightmaps?